# ¿Cómo replicar consulta de manera horizontal cambiando parámetros de fecha sin repetir código?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Aún no encuentro la manera de resolver lo siguiente:
Supongamos que tengo esta consulta

```
--Consulta 1
    SELECT 
    IdContact, 
    IdCliente, 
    Fecha_última_compra, 
    Fecha_Creación,
    Fecha_últimopago,
    Monto
    FROM db.ClientesSA.Cliente
    WHERE Fecha_última_compra BETWEEN '2021-10-01' AND GETDATE()-1
```

Necesito que la misma consulta pero con diferentes fechas aparezca enseguida de la Consulta1

```
--Consulta 2
      SELECT 
        IdContact, 
        IdCliente, 
        Fecha_última_compra, 
        Fecha_Creación,
        Fecha_últimopago,
        Monto
        FROM db.ClientesSA.Cliente
        WHERE Fecha_última_compra BETWEEN '2021-09-01' AND '2021-09-30'
```

para que la consulta final quede así
consulta1 consulta2
sin necesidad de repetir el código
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

Comment: O sea tienes dos consultas independientes que quieres unir horizontalmente, y por lo que entiendo ambas van a tener clientes distintos ¿Cómo esperas que se relacione las filas de las dos consultas? ¿Qué pasa si una consulta tiene más filas que la otra? Ciertamente es una forma no natural de mostrar la información al menos desde el punto de vista de SQL, de hecho, deberías resolverlos desde la capa de presentación en todo caso.

Answer (score 0):

Escenario:

```
Create table cliente (IdContact int, 
        IdCliente           int,
        Fecha_última_compra date, 
        Fecha_Creación      date,
        Fecha_últimopago    date,
        Monto               int);
go
Insert into cliente
    (idcontact, idcliente, fecha_ultima_compra, fecha_creacion, Fecha_últimopago, monto)
    values 
    (1,1,'20211002','20211002','20211002', 15),
    (2,1,'20210902','20210902','20210902', 12),
    (2,2,'20211002','20211002','20211002', 15),
    (3,3,'20210903','20210903','20210903', 25),
    (4,4,'20211004','20211004','20211004', 46),
    (4,4,'20210904','20210904','20210904', 33);
go
```

Una posible solución.

```
With client1 as (
    --Consulta 1
    SELECT 
        IdContact           as IdContact, 
        IdCliente           as IdCliente, 
        Fecha_última_compra as Fecha_última_compra, 
        Fecha_Creación      as Fecha_Creación,
        Fecha_últimopago    as Fecha_últimopago,
        Monto               as Monto
        
    FROM Cliente As client1
     WHERE  client1.Fecha_última_compra BETWEEN '20211001' AND GETDATE()-1
), client2 as (
        --Consulta 2
         SELECT 
            IdContact           as IdContact, 
            IdCliente           as IdCliente, 
            Fecha_última_compra as Fecha_última_compra, 
            Fecha_Creación      as Fecha_Creación,
            Fecha_últimopago    as Fecha_últimopago,
            Monto               as Monto
            FROM Cliente
            WHERE Fecha_última_compra BETWEEN '20210901' AND '20210930'
    )
    Select client1.*, client2.*
    from client1 full join client2 on client1.IdCliente = client2.IdCliente;
```

[image: Resultado]

He supuesto que los datos se deberían de ver en paralelo por el `idCliente`, pero pudiera ser por la combinación de `idCliente`, `idContact`.

Cambios relativos a tu query 1. Utilizó fechas en formato yyyyMMdd, para no tener problemas. En este formato siempre las va a encontrar, pero cuando utilizas otros separadores, puedes tener errores de despliegue en otros servidores, o en el mismo, con otra conexión.

Para el ejemplo utilizamos cte,s (tablas de expresión común), para cada uno de las querys, y unimos estas utilizando la combinación **FULL JOIN**, sobre ambos conjuntos, puedes mezclarlos independientemente de que existan registros para la query 1, para la query 2 o para ambos.

Así como se ve en la imagen,

- Cliente 1 tiene valores en ambos lados de la salida
- Cliente 2 tiene valores en lado izquierdo.
- Cliente 3 tiene valores en lado derecho.
- Cliente 4 tiene valores en ambos lados.